# Codeigniter: unable to show result in desc order with count

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i have two tables,

```
instructions 
-------------
instruction_id  int(11)   Primary key (Auto_increment)
instruction      text
user_id          int(11)    Foreign key


instrunctionlike
-----------------
instrunction_likeid  int(11)  Primary key (Auto_increment)
instrunction_id      int(11)  Foreign Key
```

In instructions & in instrunctionlike table there are many rows,
*what i want is to , get the `likes` count  in desc order from instrunctionlike table.*
  `eg. select*from  instrunctionlike  order by count(instrunctionlike.instrunction_likeid)...`

Below is what i tried, but i am confuse how to implement count on rows with desc order.
Please help me to solve this issue

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public function fetch_agreed_desc_order_instruction($limit, $start) { 
     $this->load->database(); 
     $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
     $this->db->join('userdetails', 'userdetails.user_id = instructions.user_id'); 
      $this->db->join('instrunctionlike', 'instrunctionlike.instrunction_id = instructions.instruction_id');
     $this->db->order_by('instrunctionlike.instrunction_id', 'DESC');
     $this->db->group_by("instrunctionlike.instrunction_id"); 
     $query = $this->db->get("instructions"); 
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    return false; 
 }
```

**Sample output:**

```
             instructions                Likes
             .............                78
             .............                66
             .............                56
             .............                34
             .............                12
             .............                 1
             .............                 1
            .............                  0
```

Comment: Actully, I understand from question, you want a list of users with his likes count in descending order. right?

Comment: @Rajnish yes, you are right.

Comment: please post some sample data and desired output

Comment: @raheelshan Please wait i am posting. My english not good. Please never mind

Comment: @raheelshan   I posted a sample output in my question please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whlie you do want to group by `instrunction_id`, you don't want to order by that. You instead want to order by `COUNT(instrunction_id)`:

```
$this->db->order_by('COUNT(instrunctionlike.instrunction_id)', 'DESC');
$this->db->group_by("instrunctionlike.instrunction_id");
```

Comment: Thank you. It was simple though, I am one foolish fellow.

Comment: one new doubt: I want to include another condition like. `where count(likes) > 0`  . For this i tried `$this->db->where('COUNT(instrunctionlike.instrunction_id) ', '0');` but its not working. Why?

Comment: That will check `WHERE COUNT(instrunction_id) = 0`. You want to do `$this->db->where('COUNT(instrunctionlike.instrunction_id) >', 0)`

Comment: You should go over the [CodeIgniter Active Record documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html). You will find most of your answers there.

Comment: I wrote this `$this->db->where('COUNT(instrunctionlike.instrunction_id) >', 0)` but it is not showing anything.  But no need of this code, because above code itself not giving the rows which has no likes.   Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Please try this My SQL Query::

```
SELECT intruct.user_id, intruct.instruction, 
      count(ins_like.instrunction_likeid) AS cntlikes   

FROM `instrunctionlike` AS ins_like 

JOIN instructions AS intruct 
     where intruct.instruction_id = ins_like.instrunction_id 

GROUP BY ins_like.instrunction_likeid 
ORDER BY cntlikes DESC
```